# Как вывести кликабельную ссылку в поле формы, в html шаблон. Django

Tags: python, django

Всем привет. Изучаю питона и джанго, пытаюсь сделать свой первый мини проект. Застопорился на одном моменте, а именно у меня выводятся из БД пола в форму, одно из полей ссылка, дак вот
*Как сделать, чтобы ссылка в поле формы выводилась кликабельная?*
Заранее прошу прощения, если вопрос глупый, но я уже несколько дней не могу решить этот вопрос, гуглю, но все тщетно. Сделал переход по ссылке с помощью кнопки, но как-то это не логично, хотелось бы чтобы можно было кликнуть по полю 'Ссылка на товар'.
Ниже код и форма

Form.py

```
    class UpdateTrackingForm(forms.ModelForm):
description = forms.CharField(label='Описание',
                              widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Кроссовки'}))
linkproduct = forms.URLField(label='Ссылка на товар', widget=forms.URLInput(
    attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'https://www.wildberries.ru/'}))
price = forms.FloatField(label='Цена',
                         widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': '1000'}))
complete = forms.BooleanField(label='Завершить отслеживание', required=False)

    class Meta:
    model = TrackingModel
    fields = ['description', 'linkproduct', 'price', 'complete']
```

views.py

```
class UpdateTrackingView(UpdateView):
form_class = UpdateTrackingForm
model = TrackingModel
template_name = "parsing/update.html"
success_url = reverse_lazy("current")

def get_queryset(self):
    return super().get_queryset().filter(user_id=self.request.user)

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['link'] = context['trackingmodel'].linkproduct
    return context

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    if request.POST.get("complete"):
        tracking = self.get_object()
        tracking.datecomplite = timezone.now()
        tracking.save()
        return super().post(self, request)
    else:
        return super().post(self, request)


<div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
    <form method="POST">
        <br>
        <h1>Редактирование</h1>
        <br>
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <div class="row">
             <div class="d-grid gap-2 col-4 mx-auto">
                 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-dark">Сохранить</button>
                 </div>
                 <div class="d-grid gap-2 col-4 mx-auto">
                 <a href="{{ link }}" class="btn btn-outline-dark">Перейти</a>
             </div>

    </form>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

В текстовом input вы не сможете сделать ссылку кликабельной, нужно отдельно вывести ее в теге `a` в шаблоне